# Unzip file (odt or docx) in a memory stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, zip, openoffice.org, sharpziplib

I have been developing an web application with Asp.Net and I'm using SharpZipLib to work with odt files (from Open Office) and in the future docx files (for ms office). I need to open an odt file (like a zip file) change a xml file inside it, zip again and give it to the browser send to my client.

I can do this in file system but it will get a space in my disk temporarily and we don't want it. I would like to do this in memory (with a MemoryStream class), but I don't know how to unzip folders/files in a memory stream with SharpZipLib, change and use it to zip again. Is there any sample about how to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```
 Stream inputStream = //... File.OpenRead(...);

  //for read file
 ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(inputStream));

 //for output 
 MemoryStream memoryStream  = new MemoryStream();



using ( ZipOutputStream zipStream = new ZipOutputStream(memoryStream))
{




          ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry("...");
          //...

          zipStream.PutNextEntry(entry);
          zipStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
          //...


          zipStream.Finish();
          zipStream.Close();

}
```

**Edit ::**

You need in general unZip your file, get ZipEntry , change , and write in ZipOutputStream with MemoryStream.
Use this article http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Zip_UnZip.aspx

Comment: Hi @Sergey, what is "data" variable? It's an byte[] ? How did you create it ? Thanks for the code!